# Template function overloading in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following definition.

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void foo(const T &s) {
    cout << 1;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(const T *s) {
    cout << 2;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char str[] =  "ss";
    char *s = str;
    foo(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Then it outputs

```
1
```

From my understanding, both versions have to go through a const conversion. Then `void foo(const T *s)` is more specialized and should be invoked. However the compiler chose `void foo(const T& s)`. What is the explanation?

Comment: `const T& s` -> `T const& s` -> `T=char*` -> `char* const&`

Comment: I'm compiling it and still can't believe it chooses 1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some people have pointed out that the parameters of the templates as chosen by the compiler

```
void f(char * const&)
void f(const char *);
```

Here, notice that the compiler expects a pointer to char, `char*`, for the first function and it's a const reference. It may come as a surprise, if you found that for your case it prefers the first template, but for the following two, *it will prefer the second*

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& s) {
    cout << 1;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T &s) {
    cout << 2;
}
```

So, of course, it *will* look at the const sometimes. Why didn't it in your case? Because it will only look at the `const` for a reference if the other function has also a reference.

In your case, from `char*` to `const char*` it's a pointer conversion, but from `lvalue` to `const lvalue`, it's not actually a conversion. Adding a const by a const reference is ignored by overload resolution except when both functions have reference parameters as in the above case.

Comment: what I previously write in the answer about "lvalue transformation" is plain nonsense.. I was half asleep when I wrote this answer.

Comment: BTW prior to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1401 there was a useful note which stated "The binding of a reference to an expression that is reference-compatible with added qualification influences the rank of a standard conversion; see 13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank] and 8.5.3 [dcl.init.ref].". I would have preferred if they kept this sentence and reworded. Note the wording "influences the rank of a standard conversion".. that's not random but emphasizes that it just affects the ranking, and does not constitute a conversion on its own.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is because s is a non-const pointer, so int* const& is actually a better match than int const* because it doesn't have to add const to the pointer type.

If s were const qualified then it would be an exact match for the T const* version.

Answer (score 4):

I have moved the `const` without changing the semantics of the code, just so you are not surprised when the position of `const` "changes" later.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T const &s) {
    cout << 1;
}

template <typename T>
void foo(T const *s) {
    cout << 2;
}

char *x = "x";
foo(x);
```

Overload 1 will have to deduce `T` to be `char*` so the type of `s` will be `char * const &` (reference to const pointer to non-const `char`). Such a reference can bind to the argument type (`char *`; pointer to non-const `char`) without any conversion.

Overload 2 will have to deduce `T` to be `char` so the type of `s` will be `char const *` (pointer to const `char`). This incurs a qualification conversion from the argument type (`char *`; pointer to non-const `char`) to the parameter type (`char const *`; pointer to const `char`).

A more illustrative example of the principle in overload 1 is the following:

```
int n = 42;
int const &i = n;
```

Binding a const reference to a non-const entity doesn't involve a conversion, because it's the reference that adds the qualification, it's not the qualification being added to the entity in order to match it to the reference type.

Answer (score 2):

> both versions have to go through a const conversion.

The 1st one don't need conversion. For template parameter `const T&` with template argument `char *`, `T` will be deduced as `char*` and then the type of function parameter will be `char* const &`, so it's perfect match. The function argument will be bound to reference to const (`T` -> `const T&`, i.e. `char*` to `char* const&`), const qualified is not conversion.

For the 2nd one, the template parameter `const T*` with template argument `char *`, `T` will be deduced as `char` and then the type of function parameter will be `const char*`, and [qualification conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Qualification_conversions) is needed to convert `char*` to `const char*`.

*From your comment*

> Both routines add low-level const to `s`.

The 1st one is adding `const` to `s`, but the 2nd one isn't. It's adding `const` to what `s` points to, not `s` itself. This is the difference.

Comment: He could have expected that `char *const&` for an argment `char*` would need a const-conversion aswell. Intuitively, that's not too far off to expect, IMO.

Comment: Why `const T &s` with `T=char*` will go to `char* const&`? I mean why the position of 'const' changes.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, yes that's actually what I have expected. Both routines add low-level const to `s`. But why this conversion didn't happen here?

Comment: @ZheChen you expect that the second is more specialized. I think that is correct. But it only gets to comparing specialization level if overload resolution results in a tie. That is not the case here: from `char*` to `const char*` it's a pointer conversion, but from "lvalue" to "const lvalue", it's not actually a conversion.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I am still a little confusion. `char *` to `const char *` is a conversion, then `char * &` to `char * const &` is also a conversion, I think. Maybe your deleted answer could help explain this?

Comment: @ZheChen not in the standards world - that is not a conversion. In the mechanics of overload resolution, there is a step "lvalue transformation" which amounts to copy the argument or transforms an array to a pointer. An lvalue transformation is the cheapest of all tranformations. After that, comes the "value/qualification conversions/promotions". For your `chat * const&`, there isn't even an lvalue transformation, so it's *always* going to be "cheaper" than anything that has a conversion/promotion.

Comment: @SlardarZhang `const T&` means `T` will be const qualifed itself, for `char*` it'll be `char* const`, a const pointer, not `const char*`, a non-const pointer to const. See [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262/3309790).

Comment: @ZheChen Your example contains no `char * &` which could be converted.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because when the argument is a pointer, you have to pass in a pointer.. Like this:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void foo(int *a)
{
  cout << *a << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  foo(&a);
}
```

But if your argument is a refrence you can just pass the parameter as it is like this:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void foo(int &a)
{
  cout << a << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  foo(a);
}
```